# What is the toolchain for Wolfram One?

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

How do you create and run a Wolfram program in Wolfram One? Can you please explain the role of text editors, the Internet browser (eg, Chrome), and the Wolfram Server? I've been a Mathematica user for years - and I continue to have a license - and I code in F# using VS Code, but the path from idea to executable in Wolfram One is not at all clear to me.
Thanks for any help.